# OTA set the Delphi projects Keys options

Tags: delphi, ota

How can I set the Delphi  projects options FileDescription?
when I try

```
ProjectOptions.Values['Keys'].SetOptionsValue('FileDescription', Title);
```

(title is a string)
I get invalid variant operation

Answer (score 2):

Read the comments above `IOTAProjectOptions` declaration in `ToolsApi` unit.
Try something like this:

```
var
  Options: TStrings;
begin
  Options := TStrings(Integer(ProjectOptions.Values['Keys']));
  if Assigned(Options) then
    Options.Values['FileDescription'] := Title;
end;
```